# Qt Creator no longer displays console output in Application Output window after Windows 10 1809 update

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I'm running an application in debug with Qt 5.2.1 and Qt Creator 4.5.0. For many months this has been fine, and the console output is shown in the Application Output window. I applied the 1809 update to Windows this morning, and now I only see exception details in the output window, nothing else.

Interestingly, when I "Run in Terminal" the output is shown in the command window. It's also shown if I "Run" (ctrl-R) the application. It also seems to be OK when I run the tests for an application with a later version of the Qt framework (5.12.1, in my case).

Has anyone else experienced this? I'm not even sure where to start with fixing the problem.

EDIT: More information. I looked at the Qt 5.2.1 sources and saw that the qDefaultMessageHandler doesn't output the message if a console window is attached to the process (as you'd expect, for example if you selected the "Run in Terminal option"). If I call FreeConsole() at the beginning of my application, then the output appears as it used to in the Application Output window. This suggests that the update to Windows has caused a console window to be allocated to the debug process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of you that are interested, I worked around the problem by conditionally calling FreeConsole() at the beginning of the program, like this:

```
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
#include <Windows.h>
#endif

...

#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
#if QT_VERSION <= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 2, 1)
    // Since the Windows 10 1809 update was pushed, the debug process has a
    // hidden console window allocated to it. This prevents the application output
    // reaching the console window in Qt 5.2.1 (see qlogging.cpp in the qt source for
    // reasons why). This detaches that console window, meaning the output is shown in the
    // application output window again. However, if "Run in terminal" is selected in the
    // Run options then the output will still be shown in the Application Output window.
    FreeConsole();
#endif
#endif
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the settings, Edit>Preference>Built&Run>General Tab> Default for run in terminal.
choose those options as u wish.

u can individually change the settings for projects, Select Projects tab > Built & Run >Run >Run in terminal

Answer (score 1):

It might be a bug in Qt 5.2, especially if it works with later Qt versions.

The right answer is: upgrade to a later version of Qt.
The reason is that Qt 5.2 support ended more than 3 years ago.

You should be using one of the currently supported version: 5.9.8, 5.12.4 or 5.13.0.

Note that 5.9 and 5.12 are LTS, but 5.9 support is due to end next year. So 5.12 seems to be the best fit if you don't want to upgrade every 6 months.

#### Edit

If you cannot update the production version of Qt for any reason, you can at least update Qt Creator on your system and update your development version of Qt.

Let's say you use Qt 5.9 or 5.12 on your computer when you write and test code. But keep 5.2.1 for any other part of the dev loop (testing, CI, ...) and for production.

Qt offers great compatibility across versions, if you write code that compile for 5.2, it will compile without change for any 5.x with x >= 2.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to say it's a bug, per se. I've edited my question to show that the Windows update has changed the process behaviour, which has changed the way the framework now behaves. I agree the framework should be updated, but this is a maintenance project and it's difficult to get budget for such a major update in these circumstances.

Comment: @ChrisChambers It was working, OS update broke it, framework update fix it => it is a bug. The only things you can do is update Qt, update Qt Creator or call Qt official paid support so they can provide you with a patch for Qt 5.2.1. Also updating Qt across minor versions is not a major workload, that is one of the main advantage of Qt. I have updated my answer to give you an alternative.

Comment: It's a fair answer, but I would like to know the root cause of the change in Windows and/or the debugger before accepting that a framework update is the only thing I can do (and, also, I can workaround it in my application code with a FreeConsole() call).

Comment: @ChrisChambers You can also check if adding or removing `CONFIG += console` changes something. Note that wheither or not you have a console attached, the output should still appear in "Application Output". It does change wheither the text is sent through stderr or the debug output, but both should appear.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Benjamin, it's a good thought, but `CONFIG -= console` doesn't change the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is pretty simple:

Add

```
CONFIG   += console
```

To your .pro file